# Getting Latitude Longitude 0.0 in device

Tags: android

I am trying to  get LatLong and populate it on text view.  I use GPSTracker from androidhive. and my button listener is follows.

```
btnLatLng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //setLatLong();
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        txtLat.setText("Latitude:"+Double.toString(latitude));
                        txtLong.setText("Longitude:"+Double.toString(longitude));
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });
```

I am able to get lat long in emulator. While in device it is showing 0.0 as value.

Comment: Are you testing inside the room ? I suggest you to test it outside, under open sky or near window, with Internet connectivity.

Comment: It was working earlier. suddenly stops. A-GPS will work inside room also.

Comment: Agree it works inside the room but not all the time. Dont waste your time. I spend 2 days ( How stupid me !!! ) modifying my code, while actual problem was to take device outside. I strongly suggest you to check outside first.

Comment: Are you currently on a boat in the Gulf of Guinea? :-)

Comment: Not really. @paxdiablo

Comment: @androidsuckzzz, any success ?

Comment: No dude, its not working. still old problem.